# Homogeneous or Nonhomogeneous ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

May I ask whether the ODEs below are 'Homogeneous' or 'Nonhomogeneous'?

1.) y'' - y' = y

2.) y'' - y' = sin(y)

3.) y'' - y' = xy

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! How do you understand what a _homogeneous_ ODE looks like?

Comment: See the answers to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645511/linear-homogeneous-vs-homogeneous-odes?rq=1).